# Incorrect syntax near ')'. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'on'

Tags: vb.net

I am new to VB.NET.  I'm trying to add a table to an ASPX page.  But I get the above error with the following code.  Can you tell what I am doing wrong?  I want many table rows returned; one for each product, where first cell = product name, cell 2 = NumOpen, and cell 3 = 95%.

```
<HTML>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VB" RUNAT="Server">
    Sub Page_Load(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal E As EventArgs)

        If Not IsPostBack Then              
            Dim YearDate As Date = "1/1/05"
            Dim arrYear As New ArrayList()

            While YearDate <= Today
                arrYear.Add(YearDate.ToString("yyyy"))
                YearDate = YearDate.AddYears(1)
            End While

            dYear.DataSource = arrYear
            dYear.DataBind()
            dYear.SelectedValue = Today.AddMonths(-1).ToString("yyyy")

            Dim ListMonth As Date = "1/1/08"
            Dim arrListMonth As New ArrayList()
            While ListMonth <= "12/1/08"
                arrListMonth.Add(ListMonth.ToString("MMM"))
                ListMonth = ListMonth.AddMonths(1)
            End While

            dEndMonth.DataSource = arrListMonth
            dEndMonth.DataBind()
            dEndMonth.SelectedValue = Today.AddMonths(-1).ToString("MMM")

        Else

        End If
        Main()

    End Sub

    Sub Main()

        Dim FirstMonthDate As Date = CDate(dYear.SelectedValue & "-" & dEndMonth.SelectedValue & "-1")
        FirstMonthDate = FirstMonthDate.AddMonths(-2)
        Dim LastMonthDate As Date = GlobalFunctions.GlobalF.MonthLastDate(dYear.SelectedValue & "-" & dEndMonth.SelectedValue & "-1")

        Dim arrMonths As New ArrayList()

        While FirstMonthDate <= LastMonthDate
            arrMonths.Add(GlobalFunctions.GlobalF.MonthLastDate(FirstMonthDate).ToString)
            FirstMonthDate = FirstMonthDate.AddMonths(1)
        End While

        Dim monthString As String

        Dim ProductList As String = "SELECT DISTINCT  PRODUCT FROM EXCEL.DMR_PRODUCT"
        Dim ProductListData As New System.Data.DataSet
        ProductListData = GlobalFunctions.GlobalF.GetDevSQLServerDataSet(ProductList)

        Dim ProductRow As DataRow
        Dim y As Integer = 0
        Dim arrayProducts() As String

        Dim ProductTableRow As New HtmlTableRow
        Dim ProductTableCell As New HtmlTableCell
        ProductTableCell.InnerText = "Products"
        ProductTableRow.Cells.Add(ProductTableCell)
        ProductTableCell.Attributes.Add("class", "HeaderRow")

        Dim NumOpenCell As New HtmlTableCell
        NumOpenCell.InnerText = "Number Open"
        ProductTableRow.Cells.Add(NumOpenCell)
        NumOpenCell.Attributes.Add("class", "HeaderRow")
        NumOpenCell.Width = 100

        Dim ComplaintCell As New HtmlTableCell
        ComplaintCell.InnerText = "% Of Open Complaints Complaints < 90 Days - Rolling 3 Month"
        ProductTableRow.Cells.Add(ComplaintCell)
        ComplaintCell.Attributes.Add("class", "HeaderRow")
        ComplaintCell.Width = 100

        Dim NumOpenList As String

        table1.Rows.Add(ProductTableRow)

        For Each ProductRow In ProductListData.Tables(0).Rows

            For Each monthString In arrMonths

            Next

            ReDim Preserve arrayProducts(y)
            arrayProducts(y) = ProductRow("PRODUCT")

            ProductTableRow = New HtmlTableRow
            ProductTableCell = New HtmlTableCell
            ProductTableCell.InnerText = arrayProducts(y)
            ProductTableRow.Cells.Add(ProductTableCell)

            NumOpenList = "SELECT COUNT([FORMAT NUMBER]) " & _
  "FROM(ALL_COMPLAINTS) " & _
  " join (SELECT * FROM dbo.ProductPartNumbers(' " & _
  arrayProducts(y) & _
  " ')) on EPA_PRD_CODE like '%' + [FORMAT NUMBER] + '%' "
            Dim NumOpenListData As New System.Data.DataSet
            NumOpenListData = GlobalFunctions.GlobalF.GetDevSQLServerDataSet(NumOpenList)

            NumOpenCell = New HtmlTableCell
            NumOpenCell.InnerText = NumOpenList
            ProductTableRow.Cells.Add(NumOpenCell)

            ComplaintCell = New HtmlTableCell
            ComplaintCell.InnerText = "95%"
            ProductTableRow.Cells.Add(ComplaintCell)

            table1.Rows.Add(ProductTableRow)
            y = y + 1
        Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: Did Visual Studio give line numbers for your errors?

Comment: Downvoted because the way you asked the question it is no use to anyone else, so it doesn't help the site become a useful resource, it only solves your specific problem. According to the most recent StackExchange podcasts, we are being encouraged to do this to improve overall quality.

Answer (score 0):

Print out numOpenList. This is how you set it.

```
        NumOpenList = "SELECT COUNT([FORMAT NUMBER]) " & _ 
  "FROM(ALL_COMPLAINTS) " & _ 
  " join (SELECT * FROM dbo.ProductPartNumbers(' " & _ 
  arrayProducts(y) & _ 
  " ')) on EPA_PRD_CODE like '%' + [FORMAT NUMBER] + '%' "
```

Now, set a breakpoint and get the actual string. Then check to make sure you have an equal number of ( and ). I am betting you will find more of one of the other. Fix it and your code is fixed.

If I am correct, you are probably blowing up here:

```
NumOpenListData = GlobalFunctions.GlobalF.GetDevSQLServerDataSet(NumOpenList)
```

Or in the actual GetDevSqlServerDataSet function in your GlobalFunctions library.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
NumOpenList = "SELECT COUNT([FORMAT NUMBER]) " & _
 "FROM(ALL_COMPLAINTS) " & _
 " join (SELECT * FROM dbo.ProductPartNumbers(' " & _
 arrayProducts(y) & _
 " ')) on EPA_PRD_CODE like '%' + [FORMAT NUMBER] + '%' "
```

The problem is your SQL is invalid. You can't join a `(SELECT ...)` directly without an alias following the `SELECT`. (I should also mention  this is very poorly written code, and you should break the habit of using non-parameterized queries.)

Your SQL is boiling down to:

```
SELECT COUNT([FORMAT NUMBER]) FROM (ALL_COMPLAINTS) 
  join (SELECT * FROM dbo.ProductPartNumbers('somepartnumber'))
 on EPA_PRD_CODE like '%something%'
```

If  you try to populate the parts you're concatenating manually and running the SQL, it won't work.